# make image background without using full path

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to make an image a background to my project ,i used Imagebruch using this xaml code:

```
 <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\anlysis\anlysis\Images/GeneralWay.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
```

is there a way to use this feature without using the full path and just use image name?
please help me..

Comment: [The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a resource path instead. Make sure the image is registered as a resource in the project (Right click, Properties, Compile Type). Pack notation is nice as you can move it around between projects.

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/analysis;component/Images/GeneralWay.jpg"
```

Alternatively just this if you never plan to use in another project.

```
Source="/Images/GeneralWay.jpg"
```

Comment: i made it resource and just wrote its path inside the project folder and it worked correctly thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Add GeneralWay.jpg to your project as a resource (from your Images folder) and set ImageBrush Imagesource property to the relative path of your image location i.e. `<ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/GeneralWay.jpg"/>`